# RabbitMQ on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

I'm building a Django web app at the moment that I intend to mount on Heroku, and locally at least, I'm using RabbitMQ with Celery.

As at 31 August 2012, RabbitMQ is in private beta as a Heroku add-on:  https://addons.heroku.com/rabbitmq

I'm looking at the docs, and they are geared towards Rails applications, rather than applications that run on the "cedar-stack" (which all Django apps do).  See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rabbitmq

Does anyone know if there are any plans to make Heroku's RabbitMQ capable of operating on the cedar stack?